# Выравнивание float по вертикали

Tags: css, css3

Есть родительский блок:

```
.parent{
height:500px;
}
```

У него есть дочерний блок:

```
.children{
 float:left;
 height: 50%;
}
```

Вот возник вопрос, как выровнять его по вертикали для адаптивного сайта, что бы при разных форматх экрана не нужно было отсчитывать margin-top:10px и т.д

Comment: Сделайте код более полным, что бы его можно было воспроизвести.

Comment: Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/k4Lcmdhb/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот вариант работает для адаптивного выравнивания по вертикали.

```
 .parent{
   background-color: blue;
   height: 500vh;
   position: relative;
 }

 .child{
   background-color: red;
   position: relative;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   float: left;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/165d41bg/1/)

[Поддержка свойства transform различными браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

Answer (score 2):

Осмелюсь предположить, что вы говорите про такой случай:

```html
<style>
.clear{ clear: both; }
.css1,.css2{
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height: 38px;
}
.css1{
  float:left;
  font-size: 38px; 
}
.css2{
  float:right;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.border-red{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<div class="border-red">
    <span class="css1">Hellow</span>
    <span class="css2">World</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/k4Lcmdhb/)

Comment: Вот пример, нужно по центру вертикали их сделать, как..?http://jsfiddle.net/k4Lcmdhb/4/

Comment: Если `paren height 500px`, то вполне можно и [так](http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/k4Lcmdhb/5/)

Comment: Если высота динамичная и 300 для примера, то можно вот [так](http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/k4Lcmdhb/6/)

Comment: С display:inline-block; все отлично работает, я не могу понять как с float:left || float:right; по вертикали выравнивать

Comment: К сожалению, с `float` придется использовать `line-height`, как в первом варианте в комментарии.

Comment: если у меня стоит height: 100%; я не смогу указать line-height:1; То есть смогу, но он не поможет

Comment: Еще один [вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/k4Lcmdhb/7/), к сожалению, в точных размерах. Я больше не знаю что еще можно придумать. Обрисуйте картину более полно, что нужно сделать, возможно задача решается по другому. Чем вас `display:inline-block` не устраивает?

Comment: у меня будет к примеру 50 записей, (отзывы) в чётных блоках картинка слева ( float: left) в нечётных - справа (float:right). Можно было бы реализовать через display:inline-block, но беда в том, что при адаптивности нужно использовать именно float, так как результат того требует...